# Batch File to display file name and then certain lines in the files

Tags: date, batch-file

I have a folder of .log files where the content of each file has multiple lines of the following format:

```
yyyy/mm/dd, hh:mm:ss, ComputerName, IPAddress, stuff, stuff
```

I would like to create a batch file to parse through the .log files and create the following output for any line in a file where ComputerName starts with "XPLT":

```
filename,yyyy/mm/dd,ComputerName,IPAddress
```

And preferably, I'd like to only look at files with a modified date within the last 30 days.

So far, I've only gotten the following code which doesn't even work and doesn't even include the file modified date and parsing by ComputerName.  Looking for help because I've just not done this very much, and I can't find a good example online.

```
Echo EID,Date,PCName,IPAdd>CitrixLogs.csv
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,3,4" %%i in ('dir /b "C:\LogFiles\*.log"') do (
    echo %%i,%%j,%%k,%%l>>CitrixLogs.csv
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a bit of `FINDSTR` magic:

```
set LOG_DIR=c:\logfiles
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=:," %%L in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],xplt.*," %LOG_DIR%\*.log') do @echo %%L,%%M,%%N:%%O:%%P,%%Q,%%R,
```

`

Comment: You need case insensitive search and spaces shown in the example text will break that regexp.

Answer (score 0):

REM

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=2-8delims=:, " %%a IN ('findstr /l /i /c:", XPLT" "%sourcedir%\*.log"') DO (
 ECHO %%~nxa,%%b,%%c:%%d:%%e,%%f,%%g
)

GOTO :eof
```

redirect to your `.csv` as you will...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    :: configuration
    set "logFolder=%cd%"
    set "logFiles=*.log"
    set "maxFileAge=30"
    set "computerName=XPLT"
    set "outputFile=CitrixLogs.csv"

    :: adjust commands to execute according to configuration
    set "ageFilter=robocopy "%logFolder%" "%logFolder%" "%logFiles%" /l /is /njh /njs /nc /ns /ndl /maxage:%maxFileAge%"
    set "contentFilter=findstr /f:/ /i /r /c:"^^[^^,]*, [^^,]*, %computerName%" "

    :: Generate output file
    (   echo(EID,Date,PCName,IPAdd
        for /f "usebackq tokens=2,* delims=:" %%a in (
            `cmd /q /c "for /f tokens^=* %%a in ('%ageFilter%') do echo(%%a" ^| %contentFilter% `
        ) do for /f "tokens=1,3,4 delims=," %%c in ("%%b") do echo(%%~nxa,%%c,%%d,%%e
    ) > "%outputFile%"

    endlocal
```

This will use `robocopy` (or you can change it with `forfiles`) to search for files with a max age of 30 days in the indicated folder. Files will not be copied (`/l`) but the list will be echoed (the rest of the switch configure the output). This list of files is piped into `findstr` (`/f:/`) indicating where to search for the lines that match the indicated condition. This will generate an output with each line in the input file matching the condition, prefixed with the name (full name) of the file. This line is then splitted to output only the required fields.